# SoftDelete restore specific users

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6

I want to restore a specific user. However, when I click the restore link nothing happens. Can anyone tell where my mistake is? Below is my controller function for restoring.

**Controller**

```php
public function userRestore($id)
{
    $userdata = User::withTrashed()
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->restore();

    return redirect('admin/users/trash')->with('User', 'Restored Successfully');
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('admin/users/trash','Admin\ListUserController@userTrash')->name('user.trash');//User Trash
Route::get('admin/users/restore/{id}','Admin\ListUserController@userRestore');
```

**Delete View/Blade**

```php
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">                                              
    <li><a href="{{ url('admin/users/restore/{id}') }}">Restore</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem using these modification
I have changed here in my controller

```
    public function userRestore($id)
    {
        // dd($id);
        $userdata = User::onlyTrashed()->where('id',$id)->restore();
        return redirect('admin/users/trash')->with('User', 'Restored Successfully');
    }
```

And changed my blade url into route

```
<li><a href="{{ route('restore',$user->id) }}">Restore</a></li>
```

and web.php

```
Route::get('admin/users/restore/{id}','Admin\ListUserController@userRestore')->name('restore');
```

Comment: The source of your problem was simply this line: `{{ url('admin/users/restore/{id}') }}`. You need to pass the actual `id` there, like `{{ url('admin/users/restore/'.$user->id) }}`. Everything else in your question was already correct :) Your code was querying for a user that literally had the id of `{id}`, so it wasn't finding anything.